# How to get updates and reply telegram bot?

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

This is my code that i try to connect to a telegram bot

```
namespace telegramUpdate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        TelegramBotClient bot = new TelegramBotClient("xxxxxxxxx");
        int offset = 23;
        Update temp = null;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var m = Task.Run(async()=> bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset,50)).Result;
                    foreach (var x in m.Result)
                    {
                        switch (x.Type)
                        {
                            case UpdateType.MessageUpdate:
                                temp = x;
                                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                                bot.SendTextMessageAsync(x.Message.Chat.Id, ":)").ConfigureAwait(false);
                                break;
                        }
                        offset = x.Id+1;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = temp.Message.From.FirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

after ruining message box show "One or more errors occurred." what is the problem? telegram bot should reply ":)" but it don't. I can not find out if m receive any updates or not.

Comment: i have one bot and i want to on the bot create chating module so it's possible?can ypu please help me

Comment: Please more Ex plane About Your Problem...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 bot.SendTextMessageAsync(x.Message.Chat.Id, ":)").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

you didn't execute the task. just it

Comment: You should give more detail than just a line of code. Explain how this solves the problem. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 0):

to me this same error happen recently (the code was working on Feb 2020 but did not work later) when making bot.SendTextMessageAsync i received same exception. After some research i found this topic [[Telegram Bot stops with An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529544/telegram-bot-stops-with-an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-aggregateexceptio])
that actually solved my problem.

```
    using System.Net;

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```